# How can I find the subgroups of $S_n$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

As the title says: how can I find the subgroups of $S_n$? I know that $S_n = <(1 2), (1 2 .. n)>$ and $S_n = <(1 i): i = 2, 3, .. n>$.
But how do I find all subgroups? And how do I know their orders?

Comment: E.g.: [How to find all the subgoups of $S_3$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/743285/how-can-you-find-all-subgroups-of-a-certain-group?rq=1)

Comment: See also [Is there any efficient algorithm for finding subgroups of a given finite group?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/892840/is-there-any-efficient-algorithm-for-finding-subgroups-of-a-given-finite-group?noredirect=1&lq=1), which addresses also,  $S_n$, a finite group of size $n$.

Comment: Wilson's "Finite Simple Groups" deals with the the subgroups of $S_n$ and much else of interest besides. https://www.amazon.co.uk/Finite-Simple-Groups-Graduate-Mathematics/dp/1848009879/ref=sr_1_6?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1523450390&sr=1-6&keywords=Finite+Simple+Groups

Comment: @amWhy I have voted to reopen this, because the specific $S_n$ case has been studied, and is more tractable, as you will see from the reference I posted in my other comment (check the index - there is a chapter on the problem - also coverage in Dixon and Mortimer "Permutation Groups"). I imagine the analysis would be a stretch for OP though - but an answer to the $S_n$ case would, I think, be valuable for the site.

Comment: @amWhy Further to above I see am=nother duplicate now listed, which does cover the case.

Comment: Yes, @MarkBennet  I meant to close as the second you see listed, but still had the first on my clipboard (copied earlier for a comment).  Hence I edited the primary target into the dupe-banner.